# Check to see if an object has been created

Tags: java

I am trying to create a program in which - I am putting this as simply as possible - I find the sides of a triangle.

The problem with doing so is that there might be another triangle that has already been found with the exact same sides. For example:

If the program find a triangle with sides `1, 2, 1` and another with `1, 1, 2`, then, because of the rules of what I am doing, I will not need to use this triangle again since it has the same sides, just in a different order.

I would like to create a class that I can enter the triangle values in, like `= new triangle(x,y,z)` where x, y, and z are all integers of the sides.

This is not the problem, as I already have the class. The question is how I can check to see if the triangle has already been made with the same sides as the one I am entering?

Thanks.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by merging the two Triangles with similar sides together?  Are you trying to prevent allocating an extra object on the heap like String interning?  or are you trying to use a lookup cache for performance on some kind of calculation (area)?

Comment: 1. It is impossible to have a triangle with sides `1, 2, 1`. `a+b>c, b+c>a, a+c>b`. 2. You need to elaborate more about what is "finding the sides of the triangle". Based on what?

Comment: I do not need help finding the sides of the triangle. That is why I did not elaborate on it.

Comment: And about your first comment, @khachik, you need not worry about how these triangles are formed. There are a set of rules I follow, and the Inequality Theorem is not one of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Override `equals` and `hashCode` of `Triangle` to detect "same" triangles, and keep a `HashSet<Triangle>` with all `Triangle` created so far.

For instance, if you want to print the Triangles without duplicates, you could do:

```
Set<Triangle> triangles = new HashSet<Triangle>();
for (String line : file) {
    Triangle t = makeTriangle(line);
    triangles.add(t); // does nothing if an equal Triangle is already in the set
}
System.out.println("The distinct triangles are:");
for (Triangle t : triangles) {
    System.out.println(t);
}
```

where

```
class Triangle {
    private int[] sides;

    public Triangle(int x, int y, int z) {
        sides = new int[] {x,y,z};
        Arrays.sort(sides);
    }

    @Override public boolean equals(Object o) {
        return o instanceof Triangle && Arrays.equals(sides, ((Triangle) o).sides);
    }

    @Override public int hashCode() {
        return Arrays.hashCode(sides);
    }

    @Override public String toString() {
        return Arrays.toString(sides);
    }
}
```

Note: This approach requires that you create a new Triangle to check whether it is a duplicate. One could extends the approach to work around object allocation, but this would complicate the code for little performance gain.

Comment: Two questions: 1) If I create the triangle and it is a "copy", will it automatically be deleted?  2) How could I create a new triangle without having to name it? I am using a loop to find the triangles, so how can I add them with different names?

Comment: 1) That depends on how you interact with the HashSet, I added an example. 2) If you want to name your Triangles, you'd probably create a new field in class Triangle to store the name.

Comment: Perfect! I'll let you know if I get stuck, but this is fantastic.

Comment: One last thing I am not sure how to get around: If I am using integers to set the length of each side, how could I add the triangles in this way? I do not understand how you are taking strings from a file and then adding them with a parameter I do not see anywhere else. Could you explain this a little more?

Comment: I also found this `Collection<Type> noDups = new HashSet<Type>(c);` which could take a collection and eliminate duplicates. Would this work?

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this might be to put them all in a `Set` and implement your `equals()` and `hashCode()` method so that the order of the edges/sides doesn't matter.  That way, if you give it Triangle(1,2,1) or Triangle(1,1,2), your equals and hashCode methods will both report the same values.

Answer (score 1):

1) Make sure you implement equals correctly in your Triangle class.

2) Then, create a static collection of triangle objects , and store that collection in your triangle class.

```
class Triangle
{
static Set<Triangle> cache = new TreeSet<Triangle>();
...
```

Then make the triangle  constructor private and use a factory for making triangles, so every time a triangle is created check that no identical triangle exists in this collection.

3) Now, add a factory method for creating your triangles.

```
public static Triangle createTriangle(int x , int y, int z) 
{
   Triangle t = new Triangle(x,y,z));
   if(! cache.contains(t))
      cache.put(t);

   return cache.get(t);       
}
```

The static collection will persist with pointers to all triangles that are created .

Comment: I'd have upvoted this, but 4 compilation errors in one snippet of code (`createTriangle`) is a bit much.

Comment: It's also best practice to code to an interface (`static Set<Triangle> cache ...`).

Comment: @jayunit100 i dont recall `Set` having a `get()` method!!

Answer (score 0):

Make your Triangle class use its side lengths when implementing its `equals(Object o)` and `hashcode` methods (See http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=17).  Then create a Set of ones that already exist.  When you have a new triangle, check whether that set already contains it.

```
Set<Triangle> existingTriangles = new HashSet<Triangle>();
// loop
Triangle newTriangle = new Triangle(side1, side2, side3);
// Already exists
if (existingTriangles.contains(newTriangle)) {

}
// New triangle
else {

}
```

Comment: you create new Triangle instance for any time

Comment: @narek.gevorgyan True.  Depending on the application that could be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere you would have to store a cache (possible a `Set`) of previously constructed triangles. If your `Triangle` equals method properly overrides `.hashCode()` and `.equals(Object)` then you could use the `.contains(Object)` method on the set you created to see if it already exists.

```
Triangle t = new Triangle(x, y, z);

if (!cache.contains(t))
{
    cache.add(t);

    // do something with new object
}
else
{
    Triangle cachedTriangle = cache.get(t);

    // do something with cached object
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case you define that two of your objects are equal, if each of ones sides is equal in lenght to one of the other. So one way to solve this, is override `equals()` method. (In that case, don't forget to override `hashCode()` as well.) Then you are able to do

```
if (triangle1.equals(triangle2))  {...}
```

If you don't like to change behaviour of equals, then just define your own method in the class, e.g. `compare(anotherTrinangle)`, and supply the same logic in there.

All your triangles can then be kept in a `Collection` of the sort you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

If you have logic in place to `createTriangle()` if it does not exist already, or else just don't create, then the simplest method I can think of is using a static member, say **count**, in the Triangle class.

Whenever you create a triangle, just increment it. When you want to check if it was actually created, compare previous value of this **count** variable with the current value.

Answer (score 0):

Hm, why not do something different. All other approaches have you create a Triangle object every time you really want to know if something similar already exists. Granted, the GC would take care of that object...
Here is my idea.
First, write a test like this:

```
@Test
public void testSimple() {
    final Triangle t1 = Triangle.create( 1, 2, 3 );
    final Triangle t2 = Triangle.create( 1, 3, 2 );

    assertNotNull( t1 );
    assertSame( t1, t2 );
}
```

Have a class like Side with a single attribute length. Implementing equals() and hashCode() is then quite easy. Then, order/normalize your length-arguments and put/get/check them in a consistent way.

```
static Map<Side, Map<Side, Map<Side, Triangle>>> triangles = new HashMap<Side, Map<Side, Map<Side, Triangle>>>();

public Triangle( final int x, final int y, final int z ) {
 // ...
}

public static Triangle create( final int x, final int y, final int z ) {
    final Side min = new Side( Math.min( Math.min( x, y ), z ) );
    final Side middle = new Side( Math.min( Math.max( x, y ), z ) );
    final Side max = new Side( Math.max( Math.max( x, y ), z ) );

    final Map<Side, Map<Side, Triangle>> middleMap;
    final Map<Side, Triangle> maxMap;
    if ( triangles.containsKey( min ) ) {
        middleMap = triangles.get( min );
    }
    else  {
        middleMap = new HashMap<Side, Map<Side, Triangle>>();
        triangles.put( min, middleMap );
    }
    if ( middleMap.containsKey( middle ) ) {
        maxMap = middleMap.get( middle );
    }
    else {
        final Triangle triangle = new Triangle( x, y, z );
        maxMap = new HashMap<Side, Triangle>();
        maxMap.put( max, triangle );
        middleMap.put( middle, maxMap );
        return triangle;
    }
    if ( maxMap.containsKey( max ) ) {
        return maxMap.get( max );
    }
    final Triangle triangle = new Triangle( x, y, z );
    maxMap.put( max, triangle );
    return triangle;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I read your [other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8637815/naming-conventions-in-java) and got the impression you are a new java developer, so I found the need to give a running example. 
Simply copy paste this to your IDE and run it. It should run and produce an output which is a proof of concept for you.

The input I am using here is

```
String[] input = new String[]{ "1,2,1" , 
                               "1,1,2", 
                               "1,2,3",
                               "1,3,1",
                               "1,1,1",
                               "1,3,3",
                               "1,1,3"};
```

And as you can see it has repetitions as you described. 
The output is

```
 The triangle [Triangle{sides=[1, 1, 2]}] already exists!
 The triangle [Triangle{sides=[1, 1, 3]}] already exists!
 triangles = [Triangle{sides=[1, 2, 3]}, 
              Triangle{sides=[1, 1, 3]}, 
              Triangle{sides=[1, 1, 2]}, 
              Triangle{sides=[1, 1, 1]}, 
              Triangle{sides=[1, 3, 3]}]
```

As you requested the output is with no repetition.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
public class Triangle
{
    private int[]sides;
    public Triangle( int x, int y, int z)
    {
        sides = new int[]{x,y,z};
        Arrays.sort( sides );
    }

    public Triangle( String ... args )
    {
        this( Integer.parseInt( args[0].trim() ), Integer.parseInt( args[1].trim() ), Integer.parseInt( args[2].trim() ));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals( Object o )
    {
        if ( this == o ) return true;
        if ( o == null || getClass() != o.getClass() ) return false;

        Triangle triangle = ( Triangle ) o;

        if ( !Arrays.equals( sides, triangle.sides ) ) return false;

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode()
    {
        return sides != null ? Arrays.hashCode( sides ) : 0;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "Triangle{" +
                       "sides=" + Arrays.toString( sides ) +
                       '}';
    }

    public static void main( String[] args ) throws IOException
    {

        String[] input = new String[]{ "1,2,1" , "1,1,2", "1,2,3","1,3,1","1,1,1","1,3,3","1,1,3"};

        Set<Triangle> triangles = new HashSet<Triangle>(  );
        for ( String s : input )
        {
            Triangle triangle = new Triangle( s.split( "," ) );
        if ( triangles.contains( triangle ))
        {
            System.out.println("The triangle [" + triangle + "] already exists!");
        }
        triangles.add( triangle );
        }
        System.out.println( "triangles = " + triangles );
    }
}
```

Comment: I am learning Java, and this is a problem I am figuring out myself. I finished it, and what you are suggesting is not even what I am going for. Perhaps you should display your skills elsewhere, or stick to answering questions via leading to the answer. I appreciate this, but you have the wrong idea.

Comment: I admit I am new to this site and I might have made some focus mistakes. I tried to give an answer as full as possible, as I got the sense you are learning java so I didn't want to leave blanks for you to fill. I got some feedback I insulted you in some manner, I had no intention to do that. I was simply trying to explain that I think this answer might fit better that previous ones as it is directed to someone who is new to Java.

Comment: In order to make amends, I added the "contains" line in my answer which I hope directs more to the question.